# Procedure to return first name when inputting last name

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

```
create or replace procedure p_inout
(v_emp_lname in varchar2(25))
as
v_first_name varchar2(20);
begin
select first_name into v_first_name
from employees
where last_name=v_emp_lname;
dbms_output.put_line(v_first_name);
end;
```

I am getting 
Error(2,25): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     := . ) , @ % default character The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.

Comment: Your Question title seems to be misleading... Please be specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter arguments' types such as varchar2 do not have size attributes, so replace "varchar2(25)" with just "varchar2".

See the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_packages.htm#i1006378) on parameter usage. Specifically:

```
**Parameter Datatypes**
The datatype of a formal parameter consists of one of the following:

An unconstrained type name, such as NUMBER or VARCHAR2.

A type that is constrained using the %TYPE or %ROWTYPE attributes
```

Comment: Cool it works. Some employees have the same last name and therefore the result will return more than 1 record. I got this error ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "HR.P_INOUT", line 6
ORA-06512: at line 1
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.
*Action:   Rewrite the query or change number of rows requested
How do I return more than 1 records?

Comment: Please post that as a different question.  That has nothing to do w/the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1):

```
To fetch more than more record you have to use cursor. The code above needs some modification to fetch more than one record.

create or replace procedure p_inout
(v_emp_lname in varchar2)
as
v_first_name varchar2(20);
begin
for rec in (select first_name
from employees
where last_name=v_emp_lname)
loop
dbms_output.put_line('First name/s'||' '||rec.first_name);
end loop;
end;
```